# How to custom layout directory in sinatra

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app with multiple layouts, one for admin panel, and one for public. I want to isolate them into their own subdirectory in views:

```
views/
views/layout.erb (for public)
views/auth/
views/auth/layout.erb (for admin)
```

but I got error. config.ru :

```
require 'sinatra'

get "/" do
  erb :layout
end

get "/auth" do
  erb :layout => :'auth/layout'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the second "erb" call is wrong. Change it to:

```ruby
erb :layout, :layout_options => { :views => 'views/auth' }
```

If you want use Sinatra's "Classic Style", the code you showed should not be in `config.ru`. Move the code from `config.ru` to another file, e.g. `app.rb`. Correcting the second "erb" call, `app.rb` will contain:

```
# app.rb
require 'sinatra'
get "/" do
  erb :layout
end    
get "/auth" do
  erb :layout, :layout_options => { :views => 'views/auth' }
end
```

Run it like this: `ruby app.rb`. It will by default start a local server on port 4567.

Now the URLs `http://localhost:4567` and `http://localhost:4567/auth` should work.

Remember, you should not render a `layout.erb` file directly. It is used to wrap your views. Check [Sinatra: Getting Started](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html) for more examples.